# Prisma mysql select from database where value occurs more than once

Tags: mysql, prisma

Using Prisma how do I go about selecting all the names from a table where the name appears more than once? I've been trying a few things, like this but have no success :

```
  const data = await prisma.scores.findMany({
  where: {
      personname: {
          _count: {
              gt: 1,
          }
      },
  }
```

});

example table -

```
Name:    Score:
John     4
Fred     7
John     2
Harry    6
```

from that I would like to get only John because the name occurs more than once. I would like both rows returned

Comment: Can you share your schema file?